# Filter by count of children using Rails 3

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, count, where-clause

I'd like to select posts that have one or more comments using Rails 3 and a single query.

I'm trying something like this:

```
Post.includes(:comments).where('count(comments.id)>0')
```

However I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause
```

I've googled this and similar approaches, group by, etc with no luck. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you may have figured this out by now, but I believe what you're looking for is the *having(:conditions)* relationship, Jose.

```
Post.includes(:comments).having(:conditions => "count(comments.id) > 0")
```

I haven't tested that code so please take it with a grain of salt, but you should definitely be able to jump start from there.

Comment: I think I already tried something similar, but I get another Exception:

"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column "posts.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function".

I haven't figured out how to build the correct query to avoid the group by issue.