# rails 3 how to query an object and its has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Recommendations and Approvals, I need to find all recommendations where approvals.count = 1, and recommendation.user_id = current_user.id.

I have tried:

```
 @recommendations = Recommendation.find(:all, :include => :approvals, :conditions => [ "approval.count =?" , 1]  )
```

That only satisfies one of my needs and it didn't work for obvious reasons, like the db cant make that call.  I wonder if I need to write a scope for this, but I am newer to scopes so not sure where I would go with that.

any ideas?

Comment: what's the relationship between Recommendations and Approvals? How are they connected?

Comment: Recommendations has_many Approvals, Approvals Belong to Recommendations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Rails3 syntax:

```
Recommendation.joins(:approvals).where('approvals.count = ? AND recommendations.user_id = ?', 1, current_user.id)
```

Comment: This looks right, but I am seeing the same error as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980568/filter-by-count-of-children-using-rails-3

Comment: can you post the error here? cause there's no aggregation in the query, and a similar query (with Posts and COmments ) works for me fine

Comment: Thanks for the help on this: https://gist.github.com/1541569 is the log output.  I am doing a simple @recommendation.each in the view

Comment: Make it a separate question, and let's look at it tomorrow

Comment: Hey can I accept this answer to give you credit for moving it in the right direction?  I want to be a good citizen